# Why does slice require ! to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the `slice` method to create a new object from the attributes of another object.

What I find odd is that, in MiniTest, printing out

```
user_group.attributes.slice(ArchivedUserGroup.attribute_names)
```

returns an empty array. However, using `!` ("bang") works and returns all of the `user_group` attributes.

Can someone give me some insight into why `slice` works this way?

```
      UserGroup.where(user_id: self.id).each do |user_group|
        ArchivedUserGroup.create(
          user_group.attributes.slice!(ArchivedUserGroup.attribute_names)
        )
      end
```

Comment: Btw, you probably want to use `slice!` with a splat (asterisk) to expand the array into separate args: `.slice!(*ArchivedUserGroup.attribute_names)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hash#slice!` returns hash with *removed* elements while `Hash#slice` returns *selected* elements:

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }.slice(:foo, :bar)
=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }.slice!(:foo, :bar)
=> {}
```

Also, `slice!` (with a bang) mutates hash (by removing non-sliced elements), so by conventions, this method has a bang.

It seems like you have not attributes with `ArchivedUserGroup.attribute_names` keys, so `slice!` just returns `attributes`.